# Get WFFM values and transpose them into Pivot table

Tags: wffm, sql-database

I have a situation where I am stuck to create a query for fetching data from Wffm DB as Pivot, so please help

```
FieldName    Value
--------------------------------
FirstName      Joe
MiddleName     S
LastName       Smith
Email          abc@abc.com
FirstName      Sam
MiddleName     S
LastName       Freddrick
email          abc1@abc.com
FirstName      Jaime
MiddleName     S
LastName       Carol
email          abc2@abc.com
```

Expected

```
FirstName   MiddleName          LastName        Email
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Joe             S               Smith           abc@abc.com
Sam             S               Freddrick       abc1@abc.com
Jaime           S               Carol           abc2@abc.com
```

Comment: What is your query?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about SQL not Sitecore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember that there is also FormId field in the same table as you are referencing.

I have created a similar temporar table to the one from Sitecore WFFM table:

```
create table #Temp
(
    FormId int,
    FieldName Varchar(50), 
    Value Varchar(50)
)

Insert Into #Temp VALUES (1,'FirstName','Joe')
Insert Into #Temp VALUES (1,'MiddleName','S')
Insert Into #Temp VALUES (1,'LastName','Smith')
Insert Into #Temp VALUES (1,'Email','abc@abc.com')
Insert Into #Temp VALUES (2,'FirstName','Sam')
Insert Into #Temp VALUES (2,'MiddleName','S')
Insert Into #Temp VALUES (2,'LastName','Freddrick')
Insert Into #Temp VALUES (2,'Email','abc1@abc.com')
Insert Into #Temp VALUES (3,'FirstName','Jaime')
Insert Into #Temp VALUES (3,'MiddleName','S')
Insert Into #Temp VALUES (3,'LastName','Carol')
Insert Into #Temp VALUES (3,'Email','abc2@abc.com')
```

Table looks like this:

[image]

And this is the script to transpose rows into columns:

```
select FormId, max(FirstName) as FirstName, max(MiddleName) as MiddleName, max(LastName) as LastName, max(Email) as Email 
from (
    select FormId
         , case when FieldName = 'FirstName' then Value end as FirstName
         , case when FieldName = 'MiddleName' then Value end as MiddleName 
         , case when FieldName = 'LastName' then Value end as LastName 
         , case when FieldName = 'Email' then Value end as Email 
    from #Temp
) as t 
group by FormId;
```

Table looks like this at the end:

[image]

Just change the column and table names and you should be fine...